# Newly installed Kubuntu; added support for gaming Lutris; everything works well but I have an annoying error about a missing PPA repository

Tags: apt, kubuntu, ppa, lutris

Apparently, the Lutris folks are aware of this issue - even suggesting a method for a resolution that wasn't very clear and without clear instruction.

Lutris indicated that they removed the PPA repo (meaning no auto-updates(?)) and to 'upgrade' to the latest and greatest. This statement was made roughly one year ago - so, I would think that the fix was in the release I downloaded considering it is the latest and greatest.

Everything works brilliantly. I'm, actually quite pleased. But, when I open Discover - this very urgent sounding 'warning' always appears in the midst of my list.

Any help on how to resolve this issue, specifically, would be much appreciated.

[Lutris missing PPA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co8sw.png)

Comment: The PPA is no longer maintained. Install the deb from github.